# Find text in JavaScript similar Like MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
const words = ['Bruno Nobre', 'José Bruno', 'Bruno Ricardo', 'Antônio Bruno']
const searchValue = (data) => data.filter(i => i.startsWith('Bruno'));
const values = searchValue(words)
console.log(values)
```

Its return will be: `['Bruno Nobre', 'Bruno Ricardo']`

Similar to returning the MySQL expression: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "Bruno%"`

But in MySQL, if I add another wildcard character at the beginning of expression(%Bruno%) I can find the word Bruno anywhere in the string if I want to.

But with the startWiths function in JavaScript I can only filter the texts that start with the expression.

I would like JavaScript to have the same default search behavior as startsWith, but to have the possibility of putting a wildcard character at the beginning (similar to LIKE) to search anywhere in the text if necessary.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a regular expression dynamically:

```js
const words = ['Bruno Nobre', 'José Bruno', 'Bruno Ricardo', 'Antônio Bruno'];

['Bruno', 'Bruno*', '*Bruno', '*Bruno*'].forEach(searchTerm => {
  let regText = searchTerm.replace(/^[^*]/, '^$&');
  if(regText === searchTerm){
    regText = regText.replace(/[^*]$/, '$&$');
  }
  const re = new RegExp(regText.replaceAll('*', ''), 'i');
  console.log(searchTerm, re, ':', ...words.filter(i => re.test(i)).map(JSON.stringify));
});
```

Comment: Hi, I know these methods, but the problem is that I don't want to get stuck there is a way. I would like that when the user types "Bruno" he searches for the expression Bruno at the beginning, but when he types, for example, "Bruno*" he searches for the expression anywhere in the text. Dynamically, you know?

Comment: In fact, one thing was missing my friend, when the user writes only 'Bruno', without the wildcard character, he has to assume the regex '^Bruno' by default, similar to LIKE name = 'Bruno%' Can you help me?

Answer (score -3):

To achieve a similar behavior to the MySQL LIKE operator in JavaScript, you can use regular expressions (regex).

Regular expressions provide powerful pattern matching capabilities that can be used to search for specific patterns within strings.

In your case, you can modify the searchValue function to use a regex pattern instead of the startsWith method. Here's an example of how you can implement it:

```
const words = ['Bruno Nobre', 'José Bruno', 'Bruno Ricardo', 'Antônio Bruno'];

const searchValue = (data, pattern) => data.filter(i => i.match(pattern));

const pattern = /^.*Bruno/;
const values = searchValue(words, pattern);
console.log(values);
```

In this example, the pattern variable is a regex pattern that matches any string that starts with "Bruno" (similar to LIKE 'Bruno%' in MySQL).

The ^ character denotes the start of the string, .* matches any characters (zero or more times), and "Bruno" is the specific pattern you're searching for.

By using the match method with the regex pattern, you can filter the array data to find the elements that match the pattern.

If you want to search for "Bruno" anywhere in the string (similar to LIKE '%Bruno%' in MySQL), you can modify the pattern variable as follows:

```
const pattern = /.*Bruno.*/;
```

This pattern matches any string that contains "Bruno" anywhere within it.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: All you need is `/Bruno/`.

Comment: const pattern = /Bruno/;
We can simply use this pattern.

Comment: [Another thing to note.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)

Comment: I thought about that, using the /^.*Bruno/ regex for the first scenario and the /Bruno/ regex for the second... The problem is that I would have to use one regex or another. I want to make it dynamic, if the user writes for example "%Bruno" it assigns the first scenario, but if he writes "Bruno" it assigns the second. Did you understand?

Comment: @BrunoNobre `/^.*Bruno/` and `/Bruno/` do the exact same thing.